# Исходной код HTML отличается от исходного кода в инпескторе браузера (исследовать элемент) DELPHI

Tags: delphi

Проблема заключается в том что если зайти сюда `https://wordstat.yandex.ru/#!/?words=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0` появится список ключевых слов, я хочу их собрать, проблема в том что их нет в исходном коде страницы, их можно найти если на слово кликнуть правой кнопкой мышки и выбрать "Исследовать элемент"

Как это реализовать в Delphi? Через простое `idhttp.Get(url);` выдаст обычный исходной код html документа в котором не будет ключевых фраз.

Пробовал отправлять POST запрос и в полученном ответе получил два параметра JSON зашифрованное data и какая то функция key

`data hX8L^^\u0002@[ZUN\\r[\\A\\6V\…01eQ\\\u000cZ)^\u0013VF|Io\""`

`key "var f980 = function(v342){var…).reverse().join(''));f980()"`

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, часть html-a страницы создается/подгружается javascript-ом. Используйте компонент `TWebBrowser`.

Comment: Опыта с работой `TWebBrowser` нет, пробовал пару раз загрузить страницу в  `TWebBrowser` получил кучу ошибок от самого  `TWebBrowser` что мол "не поддерживается java элемент"(алерты от скомпилированного приложения выходили, но страница подгружалась хоть и криво) читал как то есть компонент `chronium` а и разве если я получу исходной код  `TWebBrowser` там не будет ли тоже самое если запросить исходной код страницы в том же браузере фаер фоксе? Может тут надо через DOM как то вытаскивать ключевые фразы, в этом у меня тоже опыта нет...

Comment: По умолчанию TWebBrowser (на Windows это обычный InternetExplorer) работает в режиме совместимости с IE7, посему и алерты. Как изменить это - описано в https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(VS.85).aspx#browser_emulation . Хромиум можно использовать, это компонент dcef3 (use Google). Браузер (любой) тем и отличается от обычного get-запроса, что он обрабатывает скрипты, которые могут создавать доп.контент или подгружать его создаваемыми запросами.